# Not able to install grunt preprocessor

Tags: gruntjs

I am using grunt version 1.0.1. While installing grunt preprocessor, it is returning the error as:
npm WARN grunt-preprocessor@0.6.1 requires a peer of grunt@0.4.x but none was installed.

Please let me know, how to resolve this issue.

I need this to handle loading of the certain script and CSS files in a HTML based on environment, development/production.

Is there any other better way other than grunt preprocessor to handle loading of certain script / CSS for development and production.